# Получить результат из потока

Tags: java, javafx

Подскажите, пожалуйста как лучше делать в таких ситуациях.

При нажатии на кнопку, в методе onClick должен выполниться метод другого класса и в зависимости от его возвращенного значения будут обновлены надписи.

Если просто вызываю метод в теле onClick, то логично, что форма подвисает до конца его выполнения. Если же я метод запускаю в новом потоке, то как мне получить оттуда результат ведь изменять переменные нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любой код, что может вызвать подвисание, выполняется в новом потоке. В конце, результат для интерфейса обновляется методом  Platform.runLater()

```
new Thread(()->{
    // some code to do
    Platform.runLater(()-> textField.setText("Updated"));
});
```

Comment: а допустимо и возможно ли из этого потока получить значение? Например поток выполняется в методе и этот метод должен вернуть значение, которое было посчитано в потоке.

Comment: @Divine пользовательский интерфейс останавливать нельзя. Если мы хотим, чтобы какой-то метод выполнился и в результате получить из него какое-то значение, но при этом поток не должен ждать в этом месте, то откуда ему потом продолжить работу? Логика всегда такая: поток выполняет какую-то задачу, в результате имеет какое-то значение, а потом он сообщает потоку пользовательского интерфейса, куда это значение деть. Со всеми остальными потоками можно делать все что угодно. Останавливать, ждать, проверять в цикле не выполнился ли наш метод, но с интерфейсом есть ограничения